# What does this for(:) mean in Java?

Tags: java

```
package MyTest;

import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

class Person {
...
}

class Student extends Person {
...
}

public class IntrospectorDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Student.class, Person.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (PropertyDescriptor prop : props) {
            System.out.println(prop.getName() + "::" + prop.getPropertyType());
        }
    }

}
```

I am learning the above code which tells me what is introspector and what is stopClass.
But I don't understand what is meaning of this? `for (PropertyDescriptor prop : props)` ?
Usually a for() should be like this: `for(i=0;i<100;i++)`
Could anyone please help to further explain it? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html - Java 5 "Enhanced" For Loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the  [for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) syntax, introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 4):

It's a for-each loop over the Collection "props". It iterates over all entries of the collection. During each loop iteration, "prop" is the currently processed entry. You can do that with any container class which implements Iterable as well as arrays.

Comment: "You can do that with any container class which extends Collection." is not complete information. It should be: "You can do that with any class which implements Iterable<E> iface."